# Python, не могу догадаться как вместо полученного hsv значения (из 3 целых чисел), выводить название цвета

Tags: python, функции, pillow

Всем привет, вопрос в следующем: Никак не могу понять, как реализовать простейший вывод. Вместо полученных значений hsv (0, 255, 255) - в название цвета("Красный"). Цвета достаточно совсем простого, без оттенка или яркости(что в дальнейшем "возможно" объясняет некоторые костыли), так же без всяких нестандартных цветов, являющихся результатом нескольких обычных. ***Сильно не пинайте пожалуйста я совсем новичок.***

На всякий случай объясню на примере: Мне достаточно просто название ("красный", "оранжевый", "зеленый", "синий" и пр.), всякие ("перламутровый", "салатовый", "азурный") не нужны. В общем нужные цвета в палитре диапазона Hue(из Hue Satur Value).

Далее объясняю как я до этого дошел:

```py
from PIL import Image

img_num = 1

while True:
    try:
        image = Image.open('_0{}.jpg'.format(str(img_num)))
        size = (100, 100, 375, 250)  # Добавлен размер
        image = image.crop(size)  # Добавлен размер
        w, h = image.size
        rr, gg, bb = 0, 0, 0

        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
                rr += r
                gg += g
                bb += b
        cnt = w * h
        r = rr // cnt
        g = gg // cnt
        b = bb // cnt
        print(r, g, b, ' - _0{}.jpg(r, g, b)'.format(str(img_num)))
```

Сначала, я у изображения, из указанного диапазона цвета пикселей, получаю rgb значение. Все это в цикле и исключении, для перебора изображений.

Далее, для того чтобы из rgb значения получить строковое название цвета я вообще не смог допереть- поэтому решил конвертировать rgb в hsv. Почему hsv? Я скачал Colormania, в общем там есть этот диапазон и его очень легко определить на палитре Hue, хоть и не совсем детально-точное определение будет, но оно и не нужно. например: "синий" на диапазоне hue- 200..260.
Да, я видел библиотеку по конвертации rgb в hsv, но на полученных там диапазонах возможно имелся другой формат, в общем после проверки, нужный цвет не получался.
Поэтому решил конвертить сам, по формуле конвертации цветов.

По получению переменной Satur, не заморачивался. По формуле, к сожалению, нужное значение так же не выводится, поэтому наглядно понял, что в Colormania это значение вычисляется- из максимального числа вычитая минимальное.

```
        def rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b):
            global hue
            maxc = max(r, g, b)
            minc = min(r, g, b)
            value = maxc

            if minc == maxc:
                return 0, 0, value

            if maxc == r and g >= b:
                hue = 60 * (g - b) // (maxc - minc) + 1
            elif max == r and g < b:
                hue = 60 * (g - b) // (maxc - minc) + 360
            elif max == g:
                hue = 60 * (b - r) // (maxc - minc) + 120
            elif maxc == b:
                hue = 60 * (r - g) // (maxc - minc) + 240

            # Правильное вычисление s (по формуле в вики)
            # if maxc == 0:
            #     satur = 0
            # else:
            #     satur = (minc // maxc) - 1

            # Вычисление S как в Colormania
            satur = maxc - minc
            return hue, satur, value


        print(rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b), ' - _0{}.jpg(h, s, v)'.format(str(img_num)))
```

Далее моих мозгов не хватает, я не понимаю как мне полученное значение (0, 255, 255) превратить в строку "Красный". Вроде уже 2 книги проширстил, на форумах искал, везде. Функция get_color_name написана тут чисто для того, чтобы вы хотябы поняли что я хочу, на самом деле я сам уже даже не понимаю что я в ней хочу получить. Возможно у меня ошибка при вызове функции, но я по другому уже не понимаю как эти значения в нее запихать, написал, повторюсь, чтобы донести, что я хочу получить/каким образом это пытаюсь получить.

```py
        def get_color_name(h, s, v):
            while s <= 28 and v >= 28:
                h <= 0
                print('Красный')
                if h > 14 <= 20:
                    print('Оранжевый')
                elif h > 20 <= 35:
                    print('Бежевый')
                elif h > 35 <= 67:
                    print('Зеленый')
                elif h > 67 <= 140:
                    print('Бирюзовый')
                elif h > 140 <= 174:
                    print('Голубой')
                elif h > 174 <= 245:
                    print('Синий')
                elif h > 245 <= 348:
                    print('Фиолетовый')
                elif h > 348 <= 600:
                    print('Красный')
                if s >= 28 and v >= 202:
                    print('Белый')
                elif s == 0 or s > 28 and v <= 47:
                    print('Черный')
                else:
                    print('Серый')
                    break
            return h, s, v
            print(get_color_name(rgb_to_hsv(r, g, b)))


        img_num += 1
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Закончились изображения!')
        break
```

В общем и целом, я надеюсь вы поймете что из полученного мной значения hsv мне нужно его наименование, далее буквальный пример:(0,255,255(полученное значение) - "Красный"(наименование цвета)). Если есть варианты полегче от Вас, буду рад услышать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом примитивном варианте можно просто сначала сделать проверку на чёрный/белый/серый и если цвет не совпал, то тупо по H брать один из цветов радуги.

Я не знаю, какие числа правильно считать границами белого, серого и чёрного по S и V, поэтому я их поставил примерно, потом подберите точнее.

```
def get_color_name(h, s, v):
    if v < 30:
        return 'Чёрный'
    if s < 30:
        if v >= 200:
            return 'Белый'
        else:
            return 'Серый'
    else:
        colors = ['Красный', 'Оранжевый', 'Жёлтый', 'Зелёный', 'Голубой', 'Синий', 'Фиолетовый']
        key = int((h / (255/7) + 0.5) % 7)
        return colors[key]

print(get_color_name(0, 255, 255))
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!